# Send fbp Cookie with Facebook Pixel Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, pixel

Does anyone know how to send the fbp parameter for Facebook Pixel using the javascript pixel code? This is the code I currently have, I'm not sure if the fbp parameter is correct. Can anyone advise please? Thanks.

```
    <script>
    
    fbq('track', 'Purchase', { 
        value: '150.00',
        currency: 'GBP',
        content_ids: ['1'],
        num_items: '1'      
        }, { eventID: '10676' }, { fbp: 'fb.1.1596403881668.1116446470' });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Meaning of the parts is explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc

Comment: You should read the actual cookie value, if it exists, and then send that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to state the cookie's name which is **_fbp** instead of **fbp**

From what I know, Facebook fetches the cookie if it exists, if it doesn't it creates the _fbp cookie on the first call.

> When the Meta Pixel is installed on a website, and the Pixel uses first-party cookies, the Pixel automatically saves a unique identifier to an _fbp cookie for the website domain if one does not already exist. *[read more about _fbp documentation @ Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc#fbp)*

This is quite easy to check if you install the Pixel Helper extension for Google Chrome ([Pixel Helper Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc))

---

I'm not sure why you are trying to send it through the event call, but if you want to somehow manipulate it just overwrite the value of the _fbp cookie.

**What is _fbp used for?**

Facebook uses the _fbp cookie to tag a user, this is important for events attribution and therefore you shouldn't manipulate it unless you have a specific reason for doing so.